# Striping All values form XML string using TSQL (SQL SERVER 2008)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm looking into a problem where i need to be comparing a given XML to what user inputs without the values, so for example if this is the user input:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <genRetrieve xmlns:v1="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
                <checkRetrieve>
                    <party>
                        <user>
                            <first>BLA</first>
                            <last>last</last>
                        </user>
                        <media>none</media>
                    </party>
                </checkRetrieve>
            </genRetrieve>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to produce the following and insert it into another table:

```
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <genRetrieve xmlns:v1="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
                <checkRetrieve>
                    <party>
                        <user>
                            <first></first>
                            <last></last>
                        </user>
                        <media></media>
                    </party>
                </checkRetrieve>
            </genRetrieve>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

**without the formatting (spaces, line feeds ...etc).**

Can anyone please give an example on how this could be archived? I intially used the blow metoh:

```
    DECLARE @hdoc     int
    DECLARE @doc      varchar(2000)

    SET @doc = 'my xml'

    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @doc

    SELECT * FROM OPENXML( @hdoc, '/*',2)

    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc
    GO
```

but it seemes tricky to build the final XML string using the output of the table from above command, if you could show me the standard/most efficient way (given there will xml strings with many elements in them) it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you've selected the correct tool for the job? I'm sure that there's *something* sitting above the database code that is sending this data in and is probably a more fully-featured language than T-SQL and has access to more regular XML processing libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the XML data type and use [delete (XML DML)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190254.aspx) to remove all `text()` nodes.

```sql
declare @xml xml = 
'<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <genRetrieve xmlns:v1="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
      <checkRetrieve>
        <party>
          <user>
            <first>BLA</first>
            <last>last</last>
          </user>
          <media>none</media>
        </party>
      </checkRetrieve>
    </genRetrieve>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>'

set @xml.modify('delete //*/text()')

select @xml
```

Result:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <genRetrieve xmlns:v1="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
      <checkRetrieve>
        <party>
          <user>
            <first />
            <last />
          </user>
          <media />
        </party>
      </checkRetrieve>
    </genRetrieve>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```